# How do I add a particular element in the string

Tags: scala

I am facing a problem in finding out how an element at a specified position can be dropped using scala.

How do I drop a character at a specified position in a string using scala and also how do I add a character at a specified position in a string in scala ?

Comment: show us what all did you try or researched ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `patch` by @BenReich is possibly the most idiomatic and neat approach to this; another way includes for instance the use of `take` and `drop` over a string as a sequence of `Char`, like this,

```
val s = ('a' to 'e').mkString
s: String = abcde

scala> s.take(2) ++ s.drop(3)  // remove third char
res0: String = abde

scala> s.take(2) ++ "CCC" ++ s.drop(3)  // replace third char with a string
res1: String = abCCCde

scala> s.take(2) ++ s.drop(4)  // remove from third to fourth chars
res2: String = abe
```

Note this is not the most efficient approach for large strings.

Answer (score 3):

Most of this can be done with the `patch` method:

```
val x = "abcdefgh"
//Replace 1 element starting at the 4th position with "" (thereby eliminating the fourth element)
x.patch(4, "", 1) //"abcdfgh"

//Replace 0 elements starting at the 4th position with "A" (thereby adding an element after the fourth element)
x.patch(4, "A", 0) //"abcdAefgh"
```

The method is defined on `GenSeqLike`, which is pretty high up the type hierarchy, so you can use `patch` on types other than `String`:

```
 List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).patch(4, Seq(), 1) //List(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7)
```

Read the documentation of `patch` [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.GenSeqLike).

You can also enrich `GenSeqLike` to make this type of method more easily availble:

```
import scala.collection.GenSeqLike
implicit class RichGenSeqLike[T, Repr <% GenSeqLike[T, Repr]](val seq: Repr) {
    import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
    def dropAt[That](n: Int)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, T, That]): That = seq.patch(n, Seq.empty[T], 1)
    def addAt[That](n: Int)(ts: T*)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, T, That]): That = seq.patch(n, ts, 0)
}
```

And then you can do:

```
List(1, 2, 3).dropAt(1) //List(1, 3)
"abc".dropAt(1) //"ac"

List(1, 2, 3).addAt(1)(4) //List(1, 4, 2, 3)
List(1, 2, 3).addAt(1)(4, 5, 6) //List(1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3)
"abc".addAt(1)('A') //aAbc
"abc".addAt(1)('A', 'B') //aABbc
"abc".addAt(1)("ABC":_*) //aABCbc
```

Of course, if you were adding this to your standard library you might consider doing some bounds checking.

Answer (score 1):

You may use "sub-string" to break down the string in to two parts and then after adding the required character, may combine them again.